# Consul health check pass by Spring security filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, consul

I created Spring cloud application using consul as services discovery/registry.
I have configured my spring security as follow:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(myEntryPoint());
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/modules/**").permitAll()         
            .antMatchers("/vendor/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/views/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .regexMatchers("/health").permitAll()// consul check health
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

    http    // login configuration
            .addFilterAfter(springSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http    //logout configuration
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler());

    http.csrf().disable();

}
```

Normally, using this filter spring consul health check doesn't pass by this filter (public access).

But consul health check consul pass by filter.

If I use the following url I'm redirected to the authentication page:

```
 https://localhost:8181/health
```

Comment: Any resaon why exactly this Matcher is a regex matcher, but not a ant matcher?

Comment: And to add why the complexity? Only using `antMatchers("/api/**).authenticated().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` would yield the same result (the `/**` is the catch all, which also would catchall the previousmentied URLs like `/images/**` etc.).

Comment: when I took off .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() I have the same result

Comment: Did you set the management port? Spring boot has documentation how to disable health check security.

Comment: RTM https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port

Comment: endpoints.health.sensitive is already setted to false.

Comment: management.port is set with witch port? the port application or the port Consul service?

Answer (score 0):

By default consul from `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery` use `/actuator/health` to check health.
When spring-security is used, should provide & permit that path.

**Steps:**

- Permit `/actuator/health` in spring-security, then consul could perform the health check.

  e.g

  ```
  httpSecurity.csrf().disable() 
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello", "/authenticate", "/actuator/health")
      .permitAll().
  ```
- Add actuator dependency, if not yet.
- Expose endpoints

  e.g

  ```
  management:
    endpoints:
      web:
        exposure:
          include: "*"
  ```